# How to forward data from Activity class to View?

Tags: android, view, android-activity

I created layout. I added View there:

```
<app.test.application.EObrazView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Now, for example user is clicking button. In Activity is executing proper function `setOnClickListener`. I want to send information about it to View class `app.test.application.EObrazView`.

How to do this? How to share information between that classes?

EDIT:

```
EObrazView view1;
view1 = (EObrazView) findViewById(R.id.myView);
[button on click listener]
view1.newImage(wo);
```

newImage(); is function in EObrazView which I want to use when yhe button in activity class is pressed.
Unfortunately, there is an error: java.lang.NullPoniterException

Answer (score 2):

Assumed the view is from you, which seems to be the case. You have to create methods in the view class.

Then you assign the view an id in XML:

```
android:id="@+id/myId"
```

And you get a reference to this view in the activity with

```
EObrazView view = (EObrazView)findViewById(R.id.myId);
```

And can call the methods.

Answer (score 2):

Change your layout code to something like:

```
<app.test.application.EObrazView
    android:id="@+id/myView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And then after you call `setContentView` within `OnCreate` of your `Activity` you can get a reference to that view by calling `findViewById(R.id.myView).setOnClickListener()`

If you're using an `OnClickListener`, when `onClick` is called you will be given a reference to the view that was clicked, and then you can call any (public) function that you like.

If I have multiple clickable views in an Activity, I like to have my Activity implement `OnClickListener`  and then calling `findViewById(R.id.someViewId).setOnClickListener(this)` within  OnCreate for every clickable view, and then I use a switch statement like so:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View someView) {
    switch (someView.getId()){
         case someViewId:
             //doing something such as call someView.someFunction()
             break;
         case someOtherViewId:
             //do something else!
             break;
    }
}
```